# Passing value to jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I have this button in html that calls jquery to confirm a delete

```
<div class='delete' name='<?php echo $story_id; ?>'>delete book</div>
```

and this is my jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.delete').click(function(){
       var del_id = $(this).attr('name');

        $.confirm({
            'type':'POST',                  
            'data':'delete_id='+del_id,
            'title'     : 'Delete Book Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this book. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Do you still want to continue?',
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(){
                              document.location.href="sample2.php";
                    }

                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

The button should pass the value to jquery and if the yes button in the alert is clicked, the value should subsequently be passed to sample2.php. What should i do? Sorry, i am new with jquery.  `var del_id = $(this).attr('name');` is not working.

Comment: div does not have onclick event nor name attribute. That is bad HTML! http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp consider using <a> or <button> or <input> for this task, you can use html5 'data-xxx' data attributes or 'rel' in using anchor

Comment: Also ... what is `$.confirm`.  Is that a plugin?

Comment: I replaced it <a>. how do i pass the value?

Comment: see @McGarnagle 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(this).attr('name') is working fine. Try an alert to print the value.

I think u should remove the data attribute from the $.confirm(). And write like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
       $('.delete').click(function(){
       var del_id = $(this).attr('name');

        $.confirm({
            'type':'POST',
            'title'     : 'Delete Book Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this book. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Do you still want to continue?',
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(){
                              document.location.href="sample2.php?delete_id="+del_id;
                    }

                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                }
            }
        });

    });

});'
```

I think it will work.

Comment: thanks @Soumik Sur. this works for me. I just replaced name=<?php echo "$story_id"; ?> with name='$story_id'

Answer (score 1):

The `data` parameter of [JQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) should be an ordinary Javascript object:

```
'data': { delete_id: del_id },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `change` your `div element` to `button` like,

```
<button class='delete' name='<?php echo $story_id; ?>'>delete book</button>
```

Or use `data- attribute` in place of `name attribute` like,

```
<div class='delete' data-name='<?php echo $story_id; ?>'>delete book</div>
```

Fetch it using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) like,

```
var del_id=$(this).data('name');
```